# Need help for cvblobslib

Tags: python, blob, cvblobslib

I want to perform connected component analysis using python on windows 8.1. For this I hope to use **cvBlobsLib** library (perform binary images connected component labelling). I am not able to set up this library in my python 2.7. Can anybody give me the detail of this process.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running windows 7 ?

Comment: "using python on windows 8.1."

Answer (score -1):

You need to  `install some prerequisite libraries:`

`apt-get install build-essential swig gfortran cmake gcc pkg-config libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev\
libpng12-dev libopenexr-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev liblapack-dev python-dev\
python-setuptools boost-build libboost-all-dev`

A good tutorial to install it can be found [here](https://github.com/oostendo/cvblob-python)